# select last record from a relation

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this situation. I have a table `Orders` that is related to `OrderStatus`.

`OrderStatus`

`id | orderId | created`

I need to retrieve the `Orders` with its **last** status. I tried this query, what I don't know if it is performant. I need to know if there are better solutions.

```
select Orders.id, OrderStatus.status from Orders
inner join OrderStatus on OrderStatus.id = 
    (select top 1 id from OrderStatus where orderId = Order.id order by created desc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlated subquery is usually bad news (sometimes SQL Server can optimize it away, sometimes it acts like a really slow loop). Also not sure why you think you need `DISTINCT` when you're only taking the latest status, unless you don't have any primary keys...

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT o.id, os.status, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY os.orderId ORDER BY created DESC)
    FROM dbo.Orders AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderStatus AS os
    ON o.id = os.orderId
)
SELECT id, status
  FROM x
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Yep, I removed the `distinct`. The code is an extract from a longer query, and it slipped in. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Row_Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Orders.id, OrderStatus.status,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY OrderStatus.OrderId 
                        ORDER BY created DESC) 
   FROM Orders
   INNER JOIN OrderStatus ON  OrderStatus.OrderId = Orders.id
)
SELECT id, status
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

I've used a [common-table-expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) since it enables to filter directly and it's also very readable.

Comment: Now I have the really big problem that you both provide almost the same answer! I think I'll go for Aaron's response, cause it have an interesting explanation. Thank you